# WooCommerce unused images deserialize wp_postmeta Maria DB regex_instr workaround

Tags: php, wordpress, serialization, woocommerce, mariadb

I am trying to get a list of all the filenames from a set of posts in a WooCommerce Gallery, this list is the unused files attached to posts (I can't use Media Library unselected, because that doesn't search Galleries)

I need a MySQL (MariaDB) or PHP to create the list.

I can get a list of post_IDs that I want to delete, and from there I'm trying to extract the filenames from serialized wp_postmeta data for each of those posts

for example:

```
a:6:{s:5:"width";i:710;s:6:"height";i:216;s:4:"file";s:14:"/filename1.jpg";s:5:"sizes";a:9:{s:6:"medium";a:5:{s:4:"file";s:20:"filename1-300x91.jpg";s:5:"width";i:300;s:6:"height";i:91;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";s:8:"filesize";i:0;}s:9:"thumbnail";a:5:{s:4:"file";s:21:"filename1-150x150.jpg";s:5:"width";i:150;s:6:"height";i:150;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";s:8:"filesize";i:0;}s:30:"product-search-thumbnail-32x32";a:5:{s:4:"file";s:19:"filename1-32x32.jpg";s:5:"width";i:32;s:6:"height";i:32;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";s:8:"filesize";i:0;}s:21:"woocommerce_thumbnail";a:5:{s:4:"file";s:21:"filename1-324x189.jpg";s:5:"width";i:324;s:6:"height";i:189;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";s:8:"filesize";i:0;}s:18:"woocommerce_single";a:5:{s:4:"file";s:21:"filename1-416x127.jpg";s:5:"width";i:416;s:6:"height";i:127;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";s:8:"filesize";i:0;}s:29:"woocommerce_gallery_thumbnail";a:5:{s:4:"file";s:21:"filename1-100x100.jpg";s:5:"width";i:100;s:6:"height";i:100;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";s:8:"filesize";i:0;}s:12:"shop_catalog";a:5:{s:4:"file";s:21:"filename1-324x189.jpg";s:5:"width";i:324;s:6:"height";i:189;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";s:8:"filesize";i:0;}s:11:"shop_single";a:5:{s:4:"file";s:21:"filename1-416x127.jpg";s:5:"width";i:416;s:6:"height";i:127;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";s:8:"filesize";i:0;}s:14:"shop_thumbnail";a:5:{s:4:"file";s:21:"filename1-100x100.jpg";s:5:"width";i:100;s:6:"height";i:100;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";s:8:"filesize";i:0;}}s:10:"image_meta";a:11:{s:8:"aperture";s:1:"0";s:6:"credit";s:0:"";s:6:"camera";s:0:"";s:7:"caption";s:0:"";s:17:"created_timestamp";s:1:"0";s:9:"copyright";s:0:"";s:12:"focal_length";s:1:"0";s:3:"iso";s:1:"0";s:13:"shutter_speed";s:1:"0";s:5:"title";s:0:"";s:11:"orientation";s:1:"0";}s:8:"filesize";i:27713;}
```

I want a table like:

```
filename1.jpg
filename1-150x150.jpg
filename1-32x32.jpg
filename1-324x189.jpg
filename1-416x127.jpg
filename1-100x100.jpg
filename1-324x189.jpg
filename1-416x127.jpg
filename1-100x100.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use in PHP, [`maybe_unserialize()` WordPress function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/maybe_unserialize/) like:

```php
$string = 'a:6:{s:5:"width";i:710;s:6:"height";i:216;s:4:"file";s:14:"/filename1.jpg";s:5:"sizes";a:9:{s:6:"medium";a:5:{s:4:"file";s:20:"filename1-300x91.jpg";s:5:"width";i:300;s:6:"height";i:91;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";s:8:"filesize";i:0;}s:9:"thumbnail";a:5:{s:4:"file";s:21:"filename1-150x150.jpg";s:5:"width";i:150;s:6:"height";i:150;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";s:8:"filesize";i:0;}s:30:"product-search-thumbnail-32x32";a:5:{s:4:"file";s:19:"filename1-32x32.jpg";s:5:"width";i:32;s:6:"height";i:32;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";s:8:"filesize";i:0;}s:21:"woocommerce_thumbnail";a:5:{s:4:"file";s:21:"filename1-324x189.jpg";s:5:"width";i:324;s:6:"height";i:189;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";s:8:"filesize";i:0;}s:18:"woocommerce_single";a:5:{s:4:"file";s:21:"filename1-416x127.jpg";s:5:"width";i:416;s:6:"height";i:127;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";s:8:"filesize";i:0;}s:29:"woocommerce_gallery_thumbnail";a:5:{s:4:"file";s:21:"filename1-100x100.jpg";s:5:"width";i:100;s:6:"height";i:100;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";s:8:"filesize";i:0;}s:12:"shop_catalog";a:5:{s:4:"file";s:21:"filename1-324x189.jpg";s:5:"width";i:324;s:6:"height";i:189;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";s:8:"filesize";i:0;}s:11:"shop_single";a:5:{s:4:"file";s:21:"filename1-416x127.jpg";s:5:"width";i:416;s:6:"height";i:127;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";s:8:"filesize";i:0;}s:14:"shop_thumbnail";a:5:{s:4:"file";s:21:"filename1-100x100.jpg";s:5:"width";i:100;s:6:"height";i:100;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";s:8:"filesize";i:0;}}s:10:"image_meta";a:11:{s:8:"aperture";s:1:"0";s:6:"credit";s:0:"";s:6:"camera";s:0:"";s:7:"caption";s:0:"";s:17:"created_timestamp";s:1:"0";s:9:"copyright";s:0:"";s:12:"focal_length";s:1:"0";s:3:"iso";s:1:"0";s:13:"shutter_speed";s:1:"0";s:5:"title";s:0:"";s:11:"orientation";s:1:"0";}s:8:"filesize";i:27713;}';
$result = maybe_unserialize( $string );

$new_string = '';

// Loop trough the array
foreach ( $result['sizes'] as $key_size => $data_size ) {
    $new_string .= $data_size['file'] . "\r\n";
}

// Display list
echo '<pre>' . $new_string . '</pre>';
```

You will get a usable list as you espect:

```
filename1-300x91.jpg
filename1-150x150.jpg
filename1-32x32.jpg
filename1-324x189.jpg
filename1-416x127.jpg
filename1-100x100.jpg
filename1-324x189.jpg
filename1-416x127.jpg
filename1-100x100.jpg
```